# Is it possible to query under utilized VM's through Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm trying to find examples of queries that do similar things in logs portal of a VM. I want to query a VM to see if its been under % CPU usage and Memory usage for over 24 hours (ideally 30 days or so as well) This will determine if our VM's can potentially be scaled down.

I've looked at "az vm monitor metrics" but it doesn't appear to show the same information as the logs portal, or at least the docs are not very clear on how to get what I'm after if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to query under utilized VM's through Azure CLI

Yes, we can get the CPU and memory utilization of VM in one single chart by using KQL query
Below is the code

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Processor" and CounterName == "% Processor Time" and InstanceName == "_Total"
| where Computer in ((Heartbeat | where OSType == "Linux" or OSType == "Windows" | distinct Computer))
| summarize MIN_CPU = min(CounterValue), AVG_CPU = avg(CounterValue), MAX_CPU = max(CounterValue) by Computer
| join 
( 
Perf 
| where ObjectName == "Memory"
| where CounterName == "% Used Memory" or CounterName == "% Committed Bytes In Use"
| summarize MIN_MEM = min(CounterValue), AVG_MEM = avg(CounterValue), MAX_MEM = max(CounterValue) by Computer
) on Computer
| project Computer, MIN_CPU, AVG_CPU, MAX_CPU, MIN_MEM, AVG_MEM, MAX_MEM
```

And here is the CLI command for executing query

```
az monitor log-analytics query -w workspace-customId --analytics-query "AzureActivity | summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1h)" -t P3DT12H
```

For complete information you can go through the related links

[AZ monitor Log analytics query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/log-analytics?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-log-analytics-query-examples) and [KQL Log analytics query](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/microsoft-azure-cpu-and-memory-utilization-of-azure-vms-in-a-single-table-chart/)

Answer (score 0):

I use the below script to identify underutilised VMs. For a given `tenant ID`, it iterates through all the subscriptions and finds the Virtual Machines that are using an `average CPU and memory usage` below some thresholds I have passed to the script, for a given `time frame`.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [string]$TenantId,

  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  [ValidateRange(0, 100)]
  [int]$CpuThreshold,

  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  [ValidateRange(0, 100)]
  [int]$MemoryThreshold,

  [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
  [ValidateRange(1, 365)]
  [int]$TimeFrameInDays = 7
)

# Set the time frame for the query
$endTime = Get-Date
$startTime = $endTime.AddDays(-$TimeFrameInDays)

# Authenticate to Azure using PowerShell
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $TenantId -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null

# Get all subscriptions for the authenticated account
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

$underutilisedVMs = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
  # Set the current subscription context
  Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id | Out-Null

  # Get all virtual machines for the current subscription
  $vms = Get-AzVM

  foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    # Get the "Percentage CPU" metric for the current virtual machine
    $cpuMetric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $vm.Id -TimeGrain 00:30:00 -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime -MetricName "Percentage CPU" -WarningAction SilentlyContinue  

    # Get the "Available Memory Bytes" metric for the current virtual machine
    $memoryMetric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $vm.Id -TimeGrain 00:30:00 -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime -MetricName "Available Memory Bytes" -WarningAction SilentlyContinue  

    # Calculate the average percentage of CPU usage for the current virtual machine
    $averageCpuUsagePercentage = ($cpuMetric.Data | Measure-Object -Property Average -Average).Average

    # Calculate the percentage of available memory for the current virtual machine
    $vmSizeAzure = $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize
    $vmSizeMB = (Get-AzVMSize -Location $vm.Location | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq $vmSizeAzure}).MemoryInMB
    $vmSizeBytes = $vmSizeMB * 1048576
    $averageAvailableMemory = ($memoryMetric.Data | Measure-Object -Property Average -Average).Average 
    $averageUsedMemoryPercentage = 100 - ($averageAvailableMemory / $vmSizeBytes * 100)

    # Check if the current virtual machine is underutilised...
    if ($averageCpuUsagePercentage -lt $CpuThreshold -and $averageUsedMemoryPercentage -lt $MemoryThreshold) {

      $vmInfo = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $vm.Name
        Subscription = $subscription
        AverageCpuUsagePercentage = $averageCpuUsagePercentage
        AverageUsedMemoryPercentage = $averageUsedMemoryPercentage
      }

      # ... If so, add its info to a list
      $underutilisedVMs.Add($vmInfo)
    }
  }
}

# Print the underutilised Virtual Machines info list in a table
$underutilisedVMs | Format-Table -Property Name, Subscription, AverageCpuUsagePercentage, AverageUsedMemoryPercentage -AutoSize
```